# why its not open the website URL when scan QR-CODE from crystal reports?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, qr-code

I need to open COVID-19 laboratory result from the URL when scan the QR-CODE from printed result using crystal reports to confirm the printed result is the real one and not updated.

What I did :

1- I Installed the UFL functions library into crystal reports.

2- created new Formula and add the following code :

```
//numberVar barcodeNum:= {GET_ALLORDER_RESULT_PRINT_CREDIT;1.order number}; // Use if your field is a Number
//stringVar barcodeInput:= ToText( barcodeNum , 0, ""); // Use if your field is a Number

stringVar barcodeInput:=  "http://www.laboratory****.com/Orders/Result/"&""&totext({GET_ALLORDER_RESULT_PRINT_CREDIT;1.order number}); // Use if your field is String (text)

numberVar minimumSize := 1; // Minimum symbol size. Valid sizes are 1-40. 
numberVar errorCorrectionLevel := 1; // Error Correction. Valid values are 1-4 (representing L, M, H, Q)

booleanVar allowSpecialChars := true; // Allows input of special characters in format ^000 where 000 is decimal ASCII code. 

numberVar fnc1Mode := 0; // If set to 1, encodes as GS1 QR Code. Input must be in format: (00)000000000(000)000000
numberVar quietZoneWidth := 0; // Size of quiet zone, in number of modules.
numberVar borderWidth := 0; // Border thickness, in number of modules. If non-zero, quietZoneWidth must be 4 or larger.
stringVar textEncoding := "UTF-8"; // Encoding of ASCII > 127 values. For example: UTF-8 | ISO-8859-1 | ISO-8859-3 | ISO-2022-JP-2 

numberVar numParts := QrCodeSetOptions (barcodeInput, minimumSize, errorCorrectionLevel, allowSpecialChars, 
                                            fnc1Mode, quietZoneWidth, borderWidth, textEncoding);
stringVar fullBarcode := "";
numberVar i := 0;

for  i := 0 to numParts-1 do
    fullBarcode := fullBarcode + QrCodeGetPart(i);

fullBarcode; // Return the encoded barcode text
```

3- I Added the formula field into the report and changed the font to BCW_2D font

4- when scan the QR_CODE its open the following URL

```
http://www.lab.com/Orders/2100001226%20TRIAL
```

How to remove last part from the URL %20TRIAL its working correct when remove it from the URL ?

I downloaded the UFL library from a website and its trial version I think .

Comment: This is seemingly a limitation of the trial version...so the solution would be to buy a license or generate the QR-code in a different way.

Comment: @MatSnow yes I will buy a license thank you